# Module is not found on openshift in django app

Tags: django, django-haystack, openshift

I don't know how its possible, but my module can't be found. I wanted to integrate haystack to django app. When I pushed it to openshift, where I had specified 'django_haystack' in setup.py, it didn't work. So I copied haystack package from python dist to my django project.

```
.
├── controller
├── database
├── django_crontab
├── faq
├── haystack
├── lib
├── registration
├── stocks
└── whoosh
```

I added 'haystack' to installed_apps in settings.py. To make sure this package in my localhost works, I uninstalled django_haystack in python dist-packages through pip. On localhost it works. I'm trying to import haystack.forms to stocks.forms.
I pushed new commit to openshift. I get error code 500 when I try to load my site. Error is:

```
[Mon Mar 24 16:10:35 2014] [error] [client 127.3.111.129] ImportError: No module named forms
[Mon Mar 24 16:10:35 2014] [error] [client 127.3.111.129] mod_wsgi (pid=262837): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/lib/openshift/526ed6ba4382eca6ff000024/app-root/runtime/repo/wsgi/application'.
[Mon Mar 24 16:10:35 2014] [error] [client 127.3.111.129] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Mar 24 16:10:35 2014] [error] [client 127.3.111.129]   File "/var/lib/openshift/526ed6ba4382eca6ff000024/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 255, in __call__
[Mon Mar 24 16:10:35 2014] [error] [client 127.3.111.129]     response = self.get_response(request)
[Mon Mar 24 16:10:35 2014] [error] [client 127.3.111.129]   File "/var/lib/openshift/526ed6ba43826ff000024/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 178, in get_response
[Mon Mar 24 16:10:35 2014] [error] [client 127.3.111.129]     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
[Mon Mar 24 16:10:35 2014] [error] [client 127.3.111.129]   File "/var/lib/openshift/526ed6ba43826ff000024/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 220, in handle_uncaught_exception
[Mon Mar 24 16:10:35 2014] [error] [client 127.3.111.129]     if resolver.urlconf_module is None:
[Mon Mar 24 16:10:35 2014] [error] [client 127.3.111.129]   File "/var/lib/openshift/526ed6ba43826ff000024/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 342, in urlconf_module
[Mon Mar 24 16:10:35 2014] [error] [client 127.3.111.129]     self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
[Mon Mar 24 16:10:35 2014] [error] [client 127.3.111.129]   File "/var/lib/openshift/526ed6ba43826ff000024/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.5-py2.7.egg/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
[Mon Mar 24 16:10:35 2014] [error] [client 127.3.111.129]     __import__(name)
[Mon Mar 24 16:10:35 2014] [error] [client 127.3.111.129]   File "/var/lib/openshift/526ed6ba43826ff000024/app-root/runtime/repo/wsgi/digrin/controller/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
[Mon Mar 24 16:10:35 2014] [error] [client 127.3.111.129]     from stocks.forms import AdvancedSearchForm, AutocompleteModelSearchForm
[Mon Mar 24 16:10:35 2014] [error] [client 127.3.111.129]   File "/var/lib/openshift/526ed6ba43826ff000024/app-root/runtime/repo/wsgi/digrin/stocks/forms.py", line 31, in <module>
[Mon Mar 24 16:10:35 2014] [error] [client 127.3.111.129]     from haystack.forms import ModelSearchForm
[Mon Mar 24 16:10:35 2014] [error] [client 127.3.111.129] ImportError: No module named forms

ImportError: No module named forms
```

So it's basically first mention of haystack app. I logged into my openshift account with ssh and ran `./manage.py shell` where I tried `from haystack.forms import ModelSearchForm`. It loaded without problems.

I am out of ideas here, I also tried `./manage.py syncdb` and `./manage.py migrate` in case haystack did miss some db tables. Also tried restarting app. Didn't help. What am I missing?

#########################edit1

Ok, so I deleted folder haystack from my apps and added [django_haystack](https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/how-to-install-a-custom-python-package) to setup.py as instructed.

I looked what files are in my local server in haystack folder:

```
lucas03@Mirko:~$ ls /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/haystack
admin.py      constants.pyc   fields.pyc  indexes.pyc   inputs.pyc   models.py   query.py     signals.py    urls.py   views.pyc
admin.pyc     exceptions.py   forms.py    __init__.py   management   models.pyc  query.pyc    signals.pyc   urls.pyc
backends      exceptions.pyc  forms.pyc   __init__.pyc  manager.py   panels.py   routers.py   templates     utils
constants.py  fields.py       indexes.py  inputs.py     manager.pyc  panels.pyc  routers.pyc  templatetags  views.py
```

And this where manage.py points me to haystack.

```
>>> import haystack
>>> haystack
<module 'haystack' from '/var/lib/openshift/526ed6ba43826ff000024/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack-0.16-py2.7.egg/haystack/__init__.pyc'>
>>>
```

and this is my openshift haystack contents:

```
 ls /var/lib/openshift/526ed6ba43826ff000024/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack-0.16-py2.7.egg/haystack/
abouchet.py     basicmodel.pyc  dump_loader.py   listmodel.py      memory_dumper.pyc   model.py   win-dump-heap.py
abouchet.pyc        config.py       dump_loader.pyc  listmodel.pyc     memory_mapper.py    model.pyc  win-dump-heap.pyc
argparse_utils.py   config.pyc      gui          __main__.py       memory_mapper.pyc   reverse
argparse_utils.pyc  dbg.py      __init__.py      __main__.pyc      memory_mapping.py   utils.py
basicmodel.py       dbg.pyc     __init__.pyc     memory_dumper.py  memory_mapping.pyc  utils.pyc
```

These are my site packages:
site-packages]> ls

```
argparse-1.2.1-py2.7.egg       easy-install.pth     pip              setuptools
Digrin.egg-link            easy_install.py      pip-1.4-py2.7.egg-info   setuptools-0.9.8-py2.7.egg-info
Django-1.5.5-py2.7.egg         easy_install.pyc     pkg_resources.py         six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg
django_extensions-1.2.5-py2.7.egg  haystack-0.16-py2.7.egg  pkg_resources.pyc        South-0.8.2-py2.7.egg
django_haystack-2.1.0-py2.7.egg    _markerlib           python_ptrace-0.7-py2.7.egg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added django_haystack version to setup.py, deleted haystack-0.16-py2.7.egg folder in site-packages and it works. Dont know how I got old version there.